# Bidirectional OneToMany JPA mapping with eager fetch on both sides worked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

I have 3 tables in the DB and 3 JPA entities respectively in Java application.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Fraud {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "fraud_type")
    private String fraudType;

    @Column(name = "fraud_value")
    private String fraudValue;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fraud", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<FraudActionEntity> fraudActions;
    
}

@Data
@Entity
public class FraudActionEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fraud_id")
    private Fraud fraud;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "action_id")
    private Action action;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Boolean enabled;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Action {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "attribute_key")
    private String attributeKey;

    @Column(name = "attribute_value")
    private String attributeValue;

}

@Repository
public interface FraudRepository extends JpaRepository<Fraud, Integer> {

    public Fraud findByFraudTypeAndFraudValue(String fraudType, String fraudValue);

}
```

##### My use case

On a certain type of fraud, I want to traverse all the actions that triggers from that type of fraud and act on them.

##### Access code

```
Fraud fraud = fraudRepository.findByFraudTypeAndFraudValue("Type", "Value");
log.info(fraud.getFraudActions().get(0).getAction());
```

When I above code runs, everything works OK.  I get the `fraud` and `fraudActions` associations as well, without getting any error.

I was under the impression that as both entities `Fraud` and `FraudActionEntity` are fetching each other eagerly, so it should give some error like cyclic fetch/infinite fetch loop, but it didn't!

Why did it work? And when exactly will give it error like cyclic fetch error OR infinite fetch loop error? And if it does give a cyclic fetch error, can we fix it using lazy fetch at @ManyToOne side as given below:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fraud_id")
private Fraud fraud;
```

Comment: Could you please include the stacktrace you get?

Answer (score 2):

Update: A simple and very effective work-around towards the `LazyInitializationException` is to annotate your method with `@Transactional` annotation. This will create and maintain the transaction while the method is being executed, thereby allowing your code to make the necessary calls to the DB's lazy init objects. [Learn more about it here](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring).

The return type of your JPA repository method should be a List of the Entity object, since the result could be more than one row (that is probably why you are getting the null of the `fraud` variable).

Regarding the Fetch strategy, you could use Eager on that particular association or maybe [other strategies](https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/). One possible solution would be to make a second query in case you need the lazy-loaded FraudAction list of objects.

Also, as a side-note [avoid using lombok data annotation](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/), and always make sure that you have a `NoArgsConstructor` in your Entity/DTO classes (in your case `@Data` adds that by accident since it includes `@RequiredArgsConstructor` and you do not have any final variables.

Comment: No, fraud doesn't come as null, fraud.getFraudActions return error. Fraud has the reference of the object. And how do we make a 2bd query if it's already throwing the exception.

Comment: I misunderstood the fact that "Even just logging fraud is throwing the exception.". Just to clarify, do you have a `JpaRepository` for your FraudActionEntity?

Comment: Yes I don't have currently but I can make one if it's required.

Comment: @tusharRawat Check out my updated my answer. Happy hacking =)